# Problem in build android device react native

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

i have a problem with a proyect of react native

all was ok .my gradle is 4.0 i dont know if it is the problem and i dont know how uodate it ,i was try but i wasnt able to do it

> Configure project :app
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>
> Task :@react-native-community_async-storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>
> Task :@react-native-community_viewpager:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   here start the problem
>
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
80 actionable tasks: 80 executed
Note: C:\re-pro\node_modules@react-native-community\async-storage\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\asyncstorage\AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:re-pro\node_modules@react-native-community\viewpager\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\viewpager\ReactViewPagerManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.

  > java.io.IOException: Unable to delete directory C:re-pro\android\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\inspireui.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9m 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: C:\re-pro\node_modules@react-native-community\async-storage\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\asyncstorage\AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\re-pro\node_modules@react-native-community\viewpager\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\viewpager\ReactViewPagerManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.

  > java.io.IOException: Unable to delete directory C:\re-pro\android\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\inspireui.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9m 1s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\re-pro\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
at buildAndRun (C:\re-pro\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
at then.result (C:\re-pro\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: In the log it says it has trouble deleting a folder. Make sure there is no file open in that folder.